# Return only one column value in laravel's eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table settings that has a column language. I only want to fetch the language where user id is a specific user id. I have defined my model called settings and this is how i get all the columns where user id is a given user id.

```
$uid = Auth::id();
echo Settings::where('user_id', '=', $uid)->first();
```

How can I specify that I only want the value of the language column returned in eloquent?

I want to use the language i have stored to switch language like

```
  if (!\Session::has('locale')) {
      \Session::put('locale', $language);
  } else {
      Session::put('locale', $language);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take your column using query like below.

```
$settings = Settings::select(['language'])->where('user_id', '=', $uid)->first();
```

In the next step is fetch your attribute and set to Session:

```
Session::put('locale', $settings->language);
```

You don't need this conditional statement. New Laravel's versions support this

```
$request->session()->put('locale', $settings->language);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
$settings = Settings::select('language')->where('user_id', '=', $uid)->first();
```

Then,

```
Session::put('locale', $settings->language);
```

Then You can use session varaible 'local'.
Regards.